# Dwolla oauth access token in windows app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, oauth-2.0, dwolla

I am creating a windows 8 metro app but I am having trouble with getting the oauth2 access token. I can get the temporary code with this code just fine:

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri(string.Format(AUTH_URL + "?client_id={0}&response_type=code&scope={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}", CLIENT_ID, string.Join("|", scopeList.ToArray()), CLIENT_SECRET, WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri));
        WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, requestUri);
```

But when I try to use that code to get the permanent access token, it either gives me an Internal Server Error (500) or times out. It gives me a 500 when I don't have a redirect_uri, so I keep it in. Otherwise my request just times out with no response with this code:

```
private const string TOKEN_URL = "https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/v2/token";
Uri requestUri = new Uri(string.Format(TOKEN_URL + "?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type={2}&code={3}&redirect_uri={4}", CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, GRANT_TYPE, code, WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri)));
        WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode, requestUri);
```

All of my strings are uri escaped. I just don't know what I am doing wrong.

Using anything besides the WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode option just shows a loading browser window

Also I can't use OAuth libraries that are made for C# because they use .NetFramework while Windows 8 Apps use .NetCore, a trimmed down version.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

The `requestUri` looks different between the temporary code and the redirect permananent access token. It needs to be the exact same thing.